# how to migrate from express.js to nest.js, route by route

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

Is there a proper way to migrate an app based on express.js to a nest.js app, doing so route by route ?
I couldn't find official documentation or open question about this.

Only support i could find was this opened question: [Migrating Express application to NestJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64244716/migrating-express-application-to-nestjs)

Comment: Hey did you find anything on this?

Comment: Well from what I know its not possible. Since nest start a server on its own. You would need 2 servers, the legacy and the new one and then migrate endpoint by endpoint as you please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been long time since you asked but FWIW here we go for anyone who inherited legacy Express app like I just did.

You can use your legacy Express application as part of NestJS using `ExpressAdapter`. You just create (or import) the `express()` app with all it's routes and then start Nest. The routes from legacy should be there so over time you just add routes to the Nest controllers/services modules and delete them from the legacy app.

```js
import express, {json, urlencoded} from "express";
// imports legacy API; the file exports `module.exports = router;`
// where router is `const router = express.Router();`
import api from './legacy/routes/api.cjs';

config();

const expressApp = express();
expressApp.use(json());
expressApp.use(urlencoded({extended: false}));
expressApp.use('/api', api);

async function bootstrap() {
  const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

You **should NOT start the server in the legacy** app as Nest will do that for you. Comment out something like this that might be there in legacy:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => logger.logger.info(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

It seems to work for me so far.

Comment: its been indeed a long time ! i wish i had this before haha !

Comment: @Sufiane yup, it is kind of interesting there are not many examples or docs available. I envy you that you have probably already finished this, I have a long journey ahead :(

Comment: keep the faith ! its gonna be quicker than you think !